# How to define a list of Types in clojure?

Tags: clojure

I want to have something to define my UDT so the following

```
(defrecord Foo [a b])
```

Now i can declare an instance of this type as

```
(def f (Foo. 10 20))
```

but how do i have a java like array of these in clojure.

I want to have `new ArrayList<Foo>()` (or something close), so that I can call Add method repeatedly to add new Foo to the list.

Can't seem to find a  way to do that.

Edit:

I need to tell clojure to map my things to the keys of Foo. So, i need a way to to say go through my foo-data, and then make an ArrayList Out of it of type Foo

```
(defrecord Foo [a b c])
(def foo-data
  [ "foo1"   1 8
    "foo2"   2 7
    "foo3"   3 6
    "foo4"   4 5])
```

I can access these by a doseq but then i need to make a ArrayList and then work with 
that to do some manipulation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd suggest using the built-in Clojure functionality which automatically creates a constructor function:

```
 (defrecord Foo [a b])

 (->Foo 1 2)   ;; auto-generated constructor
 => #user.Foo{:a 1, :b 2}
```

Then you can use standard Clojure higher order functions to construct whatever collection of `Foo`s you like, e.g.

```
(def foo-data [["Bob" 2] 
               ["Fred" 4] 
               ["Len" 6]])

(into [] (map (partial apply ->Foo) foo-data))
=> (A vector of Foos with the provided data)
```

Answer (score 3):

It will be as simple as:

```
user=> (import 'java.util.ArrayList)
user=> (def data (ArrayList.)) 
#'user/data
user=> (.add data (Foo. 10 20))
```

I would suggest to use clojure data structure like vector for such scenarios.

Vector example:

```
user=> (def data (atom []))
#'user/data
user=> (swap! data conj (Foo. 10 20)) ;Add item to data vector
```

Comment: (def data (ArrayList.)), is this declaring a new instance of ArrayList and then you are calling the add method on data ? How would I use a vector in this case ? any examples ?

Comment: So, when I do (.get data 0), how do I tell the compiler that I am getting a type foo ? So I have to do casting, do we have generics in clojure as well ?

Comment: Why do you need to tell the compiler you're getting type foo? You can use type hinting in some situations, but you're going to be better off most of the time just accepting that it's a dynamic language unless you need to interface back to Java.

Comment: @JimDowning please see my edited question, i may be still stuck in static language world thinking..

Comment: I second Jim Downing's advice. It sounds like you're trying to use Clojure with a type system as if it was Java. Much better to embrace the philosophy of the Clojure and think less about types – it's the path of least resistance!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to pass the ArrayList back to something strongly typed straight away, it's best to manipulate your data structure in Clojure. I find the "Seq In, Seq Out" section of http://clojure.org/cheatsheet a handy reference. If you prefer to learn by example, http://www.4clojure.com is awesome for learning data structure transformations.